# ¿Como pasar una matriz de un JFrame a otro JFrame en Netbeans?

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo una matriz en un `JFrame` en el cual capturo los datos, al darle click a un botón de ese *frame* se tiene que abrir una segunda ventana donde me muestre la matriz capturada dentro de una tabla.

Intenté usar variables en ambos frames pero no funciona.

Comment: Si el otro JFrame es otra clase aparte, entonces en esta otra ventana puedes poner una variable global llamada matriz y del mismo tipo de la matriz que quieres utilizar, en el constructor pasale como parametro la matriz y dentro colocas this.matriz = matriz, y con esto podras utilizar la variable matriz en la otra ventana

Comment: Utilizas textbox para capturar los datos? si es así los tienes públicos o privados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static class Formulario1 extends JFrame {

        private JButton btn;

        public Formulario1() {
            super("Llamada");

            btn = new JButton("Llamar");

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(btn, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            setSize(100, 100);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            btn.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {
                final Formulario2 frm = new Formulario2(new Object[]{"Dato1", "Dato2", "Dato3", 15});
                frm.setVisible(true);
            });

            setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    public static class Formulario2 extends JFrame {

        private Object[] arr;

        private JList lst;
        private DefaultListModel mdl;

        public Formulario2(Object[] arr) {
            super();

            this.arr = arr;

            lst = new JList();
            mdl = new DefaultListModel();

            lst.setModel(mdl);

            add(lst);
            mostrarDatos();
        }

        public void mostrarDatos() {
            if (arr != null && arr.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    mdl.addElement(arr[i].toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! me sirvió bastante bien aunque ya había entregado el programa <3